# Confusion between [T] and &[T]

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I'm currently confused by `[T]` and `&[T]` in Rust. Let's start by what I know:

- `[T; n]` is an array of n elements,
- `&[T; n]` is a pointer to an array with n elements,
- `[T]` is unsized and points to sequence of elements `T`, while
- `&[T]` is a sized fat pointer and points to a sequence of elements `T`.

My confusion starts with the naming convention of the two items. From the [documentation of Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#other-slices), they provide the following example:

```
let a: [i32; 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // An array of type [T, n]
let slice: &[i32] = &a[1..3]; // A slice of type &[T]
```

and states

> This slice has the type &[i32].

So, I assume `&[T]` is called **a slice**. What's the name of the item `[T]` so ? What is the usage of `[T]` exactly ? You can't embed it into a struct (it's unsized), you can't take this type in parameter for the same reason. I can't figure out a practical usage of it.

Thanks!

Comment: simple, `let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` is not a `[T]`, it's an array `[T; 5]`. you can't construct a `[T]`

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your comment. I understood the array types (`[T, n]`). My question is really about the the slice types.

Comment: and my comment is about slice - - https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html#other-slices

Comment: Thanks, but you just relinked the article I initially provided in my post. AFAIK, `[T]` is a valid type in Rust, and this is the purpose of my thread: I'm interested to know its difference with `&[T]`. I edited my question to make it clear that I knew that the value `a` was effectively an array and not a `[T]`.

Comment: *"`&[T]` is a sized fat pointer"* I did *not* know they could be called like that, thanks for the laugh haha

Comment: put it simply, both are slice, but you can't construct a `[T]` because it doesn't have a size. To have an usable slice you need indirection somewhere `&[T]`.

Comment: People don't tend to call `[T]` by any name, because it is almost never useful by itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's the name of the item `[T]` so ? What is the usage of `[T]` exactly ?

`[T]` is a block of contiguous memory, filled with items of type `T`. It is rarely referred to by name directly because it needs to be behind a pointer to be useful. That is usually a `&[T]`, commonly referred to as a slice, but could also be other pointer types.

The term "slice" is overloaded, but it is not usually a cause of confusion since it really doesn't come up much. In general, if the word "slice" is used by itself then it means `&[T]`. If it has some other modifier, then it probably refers to a different pointer type. For example `Box<[T]>` is a ["boxed slice"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) and `Rc<[T]>` might be called a "ref-counted slice".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I have now a better visualisation of what is behind `[T]`. *`[T]` is a block of contiguous memory* has been helpful to understand what is behind the type. When thinking about an applied case of those two types, I would say that in the case of a string (compiled with the executable), `[T]` would correspond to the raw string characters stored in the read-only segment of the program, while `&[T]` is a fat pointer that contains a pointer to the sequence of characters and its length (while in reality, Rust handles strings using `str` for `[T]` and `&str` for `&[T]`).

Comment: [The Rust documentation uses the term "slice" for the dynamically sized type `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html), but I agree that it is also often used for `&[T]`.

Comment: I suggest using "bare slice" for `[T]` to distinguish it from `&[T]`, since both are commonly called "slices".

Comment: Hey @SvenMarnach and @trentcl, thanks for your feedbacks. Interestingly, the link you provided defines slices as *a view into a block of memory represented as a pointer and a length*, which corresponds to the fat pointer `&[T]` (`[T]` is unsized). Also, the documentation states: *The **shared slice** type is `&[T]`, while the **mutable slice** type is `&mut [T]`*, which is the standard convention for calling references in Rust. Using the term *bare slice* for `[T]` would makes those names non ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding slices:

E.g. string literals are slices of type &str. But slices of Strings (of type String) are also of type &str such as `slice: &str = &String [0..n-1]`.

Furthermore, slice: &[T] in:

- Arrays like `array: [T; n]` - if you want a piece of it, you can take a `slice = &array [1..n-1]` which means that slice is of type &[T].
- Vectors such as `vector: Vec<T>` you can take a part of it as a slice: &[T].

Comment: "A slice is a piece of information stored on the stack that references data.", a slice can be boxed without problem, there is not requirement to be on the stack.

Comment: @Stargateur I meant that since slices are references, the slice itself &[T] is located on the stack pointing to the storage in the heap. When you have Box<[T]>, the [T] is a block of contiguous memory, not a slice.