# Why doesn't ChunksExact<T> have a size known at compile-time?

Tags: rust, vector, slice

I'd like to copy one `Vec` into another, in *chunks* of `[u8; 4]` assigning the first **3** element of each chunk only(leaving the 4th alone). This seems like a practical way to go about it:

```
    let input_pix: Vec<u8> = ...;
    let mut output_pix: Vec<u8> = vec![255; input_pix.len()];
    for (input_chunk, output_chunk) in input_pix.chunks(4).zip(output_pix.chunks_exact_mut(4)) {
       let i: u8 = foo(...);
       output_chunk[0..2].clone_from_slice([i,3]);
    }
```

...**BUT** the compiler doesn't like it. In fact *slicing* `output_chunk` at all throws an error. Most simply:

```
        ...
        for (input_chunk, output_chunk) in input_pix.chunks(4).zip(output_pix.chunks_exact_mut(4)) {
           let s = format!("{:?}", output_chunk[0..2]);
        }
```

Results in...

```
    |
40  |         let s = format!("{:?}", output_chunk[0..2]);
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

From the docs:

> The chunks are slices and do not overlap. If chunk_size does not
> divide the length of the slice, then the last up to chunk_size-1
> elements will be omitted and can be retrieved from the remainder
> function of the iterator.
>
> Due to each chunk having exactly chunk_size elements, the compiler can
> often optimize the resulting code better than in the case of chunks.

So... it seems it is saying size of the elements of a `ChunksExactMut` (returned from `chunks_exact_mut`) is exact and in this case *4*, so what gives? Knowing the size at compile time feels like it is kind of *the point* of `ChunksExactMut`.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there some more idiomatic way to copy into a slice of `ChunksExactMut`. I can simply copy element wise with a loop but that seems very smelly. Or perhaps that *IS* the way to do this and I should *let the compiler* do the work?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57808948/confusion-between-t-and-t for the difference between `output_chunk[0..2]` and `&output_chunk[0..2]`.

Comment: it can't have its size known at compile-time since the size is based on a normal parameter, which may only be known at run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Just change it to

```
let s = format!("{:?}", &output_chunk[0..2]);
//                     ^^^ the important bit
```

When indexing a slice (of type `&[T]`) by a range, the return type is `[T]`. Being sized is a property of the type rather than a property of the values. So even if we're indexing with a known width (i.e. `0..2`), we still get an unsized type as output.

One downside of being unsized is that values of that type can't be passed to functions. Thus, in order to format elements of such a type as a string, we have to pass a pointer. The easiest way to do this is to simply borrow the slice.

Doesn't work:

```
fn foo(slice: &[u8]) -> String {
    format!("{:?}", slice[0..2])
}
```

Does work:

```
fn foo(slice: &[u8]) -> String {
    format!("{:?}", &slice[0..2])
}
```

Comment: That the ticket